# Why isn't document.ready() working on this page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a simple jquery code to highlight the nav menu.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#header .mm a').each(function(){

    if( $(this).attr('href') == window.location.href ){
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }

    var value = window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

    if( $(this).attr('href') == '/site/' && (value == '') ){
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }

});
});
```

On this page right here: http://perfectlanding.com.au/creativity

I have no idea why the code won't run. There are no errors in the console.

Comment: the code is above or below the body?

Comment: Oh my god. Did you try visiting the site he linked to?!

Comment: How exactly do you know that it's not running? Have you added `console.log()` calls to the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code isn't inside a script tag. Fix that and it should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the page source, the script in question isn't between any  tags. You can see it being emitted at the bottom of the page below the page's footer.

Answer (score 0):

Copy paste this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#header .mm a').each(function(){

    if( $(this).attr('href') == window.location.href ){
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }

    var value = window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

    if( $(this).attr('href') == '/site/' && (value == '') ){
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }

  });
});
</script>
```